# Jmeter BeanShell - compare between int to counter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm trying to compare int (parse from string) to counter in BeanShell assertion.

my code:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("count_2"));

counter = vars.get("counter");


if (i != counter)


{

 Failure = true;
 FailureMessage = "failed";

} else {

    Failure = false;
}
```

On debug sampler I can see that both "count_2" and "counter" have the same values in all loop runs, but the assertion fails.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: use integers everywhere**

Change this line:

```
counter = vars.get("counter");
```

To:

```
int counter = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counter"));
```

**Option 2: use strings everywhere**

```
String  i = vars.get("count_2");

String counter = vars.get("counter");

if (!i.equals(counter))
...
```

[JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) can be either Strings or Objects, so you need to cast them to the types you need to work with.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for essential information on scripting in JMeter and some form of cookbook.